# c# how can I append a string variable on to the end of consoleColor

Tags: c#, string, variables, append

I have this code that asks the user to insert their favourite colour. That choice needs to then be appended on to the end of `consoleColor` but how do I do this?

```
string colour;
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your favourite colour: ");
colour = Console.ReadLine();
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.???
Console.WriteLine("choose colour");
```

How to I append my string `colour` variable?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Using `Enum.Parse`

```
Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), colour);
```

Using `TryParse`

```
    ConsoleColor consoleColor;
    if (Enum.TryParse<ConsoleColor>(colour, out consoleColor))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor;
    }
    else
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("You've entered invalid color!")
    }
```

Since `ConsoleColor` is an enum you could parse it from string using `Enum.Parse`.

You could also use `Enum.TryParse` when you're not sure with input color is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your favorite color: ");
string colorName = Console.ReadLine();
ConsoleColor color;

if (Enum.TryParse(colorName, out color))
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    Console.WriteLine("This is your favorite color!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, that color is not recognized.");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

You probably want some error handling like above because the user could enter anything...  It might be best to create a loop such as a `while` or `do while` loop to ask them to enter again in case there was an error.